# Keep running into the same deployment error (Exec Format Error) when pushing Node.js Docker from local (Apple M1) to Heroku

Tags: node.js, docker, heroku, apple-m1

Error I get when releasing image

```
2021-04-07T06:30:58.443089+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2021-04-07T06:31:01.899268+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Exec format error
```

I went back to the most simple node.js code that only requires Express.
Can not get my head around it what could be wrong.

Setup is as following:

- running Docker Desktop on Mac (Apple M1)
- installed latest Heroku, latest NPM, latest Node
- working with VS Code
- dockerfile setup:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY index.js .
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

- package.json

```
{
  "name": "SigningV2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  }
}
```

- Procfile

```
web: npm start
```

- added two variables online

```
- PORT: 3000
- USE_NPM_INSTALL: TRUE  (also tried without, same result)
```

ps: when running heroku local web, it works

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Ok, found a working solution. It's Apple M1 that is breaking this standard setup (again) :(

We need to force the correct platform to be compatible by Heroku.
To do this, we are going to use Docker buildx. Note, do not use Heroku:container push because as far as I know, that does not support the forcing of different platforms.

What worked for me is the following sequence:

```
# replace signingv2 with your own tag
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t signingv2 .

# make sure to use the name of your Heroku app
docker tag signingv2 registry.heroku.com/signingv2/web

# use docker push to push it to the Heroku registry
docker push registry.heroku.com/signingv2/web

# then use heroku release to activate
heroku container:release web -a signingv2
```

Hope that Docker for Apple M1 is supported on several platforms soon.

Comment: It is Nov 2021 and this appears to have solved the very mysterious Heroku H10 error I kept getting: "Error: Exec format error". I'm on an M1 2020 MBP. Why Heroku's cli `container:build` doesn't account for a change in architecture, not sure.

Comment: This was so helpful! Thank you so much for taking the time. Running on M1 and having had no clue about the nitty-gritty details of architectural differences, I had no clue why my images/containers worked on my machine while they failed on GCP, Heroku, Digital Ocean, etc. Also didn't know about buildx before. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 12):

In my case I solved the issue by changing the Dockerfile.

I updated it to pull node image for linux/amd64:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:14.17.0-alpine
```

Rebuild, push to heroku and it should work fine then.

Answer (score 1):

I modified @Jinxvar 's solution slightly as I had to use the `--load` option to be able to push the image. Otherwise, it didn't even show up when I ran `docker image ls`

Here's what worked for me:

```
$ docker buildx build --load --platform linux/amd64 -t registry.heroku.com/app_name/web .

$ docker push registry.heroku.com/app_name/web:latest
```

Answer (score 0):

Jinxvar solution works. I had a different issue after

```
"message": "no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx", user "xxx", database "xxx", SSL off"
```

If your using Postgres for the DB and get the exit error make sure to include this in your pg config.

```
"ssl": true,
"extra": {
  "ssl": { "rejectUnauthorized": false }
},
```

This route is probably not safe to run in production though. When it is ready for production change the config above to

```
"SSL": {
"ca": process.env.<your-SSL-cert-var>,
```

}