# exec /usr/java/openjdk-20/bin/java: exec format error while running docker image AWS ECS fargate

Tags: java, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I'm trying to run a docker image hosted in AWS ECR from ECS Fargate. But i'm getting below error while running the task.

```
exec /usr/java/openjdk-20/bin/java: exec format error
```

I was able to run this in locally via docker image. I'm using apple M1.
I'm using java 20.

```
FROM openjdk:20
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

This is java version in pom file as well.

```
<properties>
    <java.version>20</java.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: You've built the image on a system with an ARM processor, and are trying to run it in an environment with an x86 processor.  See for example [Keep running into the same deployment error (Exec Format Error) when pushing Node.js Docker from local (Apple M1) to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66982720/keep-running-into-the-same-deployment-error-exec-format-error-when-pushing-nod).

Comment: If you're going to build an image on your apple M1 ARM process, you will have to run it on AWS Graviton ARM processors. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/11/aws-fargate-amazon-ecs-aws-graviton2-processors/

Comment: I was able fix by changing the OS architecture to linux ARM when creating task definition in AWS fargate.